# how to get table record just after insertion in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I am working on sql query where i am going to insert record in table named filess having fields(ID,Name)

I want to fetch all records from the table "filess" just after successful insertion of record. For this i wrote the following stored procedure

```
USE [sps]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SP_InsTestFile]    
Script Date: 25-05-2015 11:21:19 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[SP_InsTestFile]
@ID int,
@Name varchar(50)
as
begin try
insert into filess(Name) values (@Name)
Declare @IDD int=@@IDENTITY
select 'y'

IF(@IDD>0)
BEGIN

    select * from filess
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    select 'n'
END
 --select 'Y'
  end try
   begin catch
   select 'X'
  end catch
```

but the query in the stored procedure is returning only 'y' after successful insertion but i want all records from table filess and the value y or n. Please help me someone.

Comment: lookup the OUTPUT clause

Comment: executing the procedure in SSMS?

Comment: yes the procedure is running in SSMS

Comment: Could you confirm the `filess` table's `ID` column contains the `IDENTITY` ?

Comment: can you share us the table structure of filess table

Comment: the table 'filess' has 2 column (ID int contains identity-autoincrement,  Name nvarchar(50))

Comment: You should probably be checking @@error, since as far as I can figure out, you're trying to do error handling here -- or have a try - catch block for handling the insert. Returning the whole table back doesn't really sound like a good idea, though.

Answer (score 0):

you can return the "Y' or "N" as out parameters from the proc and use the `select` command to get the table records instead.

Answer (score 0):

Hope the `filess` table dont have the `IDENTITY` for the `ID` column.

See the below two examples to find the difference between having with or with out the `IDENTITY` of the column.

Table [With out IDENTITY](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e3a6e/6) column, returns the `@@IDENTITY` as `null`

Table [With IDENTITY](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/64610/10) column, returns the valid number for the `@@IDENTITY`

So, if `@@IDENTITY` returns `null`, then `IF(@IDD>0)` failed and not executing any more.